# Can I install VS 2012/2013 on WIndows Azure?

Tags: azure

I am interested in running the following lab, but after finishing it, it wouldnt be complete if I cant develop inside this new farm.

Is it legally possible to install vs 2012 or 2013 inside the new SP server?

hands on lab is here
http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/07/step-by-step-build-a-free-sharepoint-2013-lab-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-31-days-of-servers-in-the-cloud-part-7-of-31.aspx#.Uv5h0_ldVS5

Comment: Assuming you have the license for the instance of VS, I don't know why you couldn't. Nothing stops you from installing VS on a local machine running SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the legal license.